# Modularizing and distributing bash script via Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, bash

### Context

I have some functions defined in my `~/.bashrc` which I'd like to turn into a Homebrew package. Currently, these functions act as custom commands on my command line:

```sh
# .bashrc
function foo() {
    # do something interesting
}

# at terminal
$ foo
# => does the interesting thing
```

### Approach

I've created a homebrew formula using `brew create`. My current approach is as follows:

1. Move the function definitions into a separate file, `script`, within a directory, `brew-script`
2. Make `brew-script` downloadable as a tarball, `brew-script.tar.gz`
3. Have my brew formula append text to the end of `~/.bash_profile` to include `script` when terminal session starts

### Concerns

1. Is modifying `.bash_profile` in a brew formula bad practice? (eg. when uninstalling with `brew uninstall script`, brew should somehow remove the text that was appended to `.bash_profile`... Parsing `.bash_profile` doesn't seem very fun.)
2. Is there a convention already established for including functions in bash scripts so that they are available from the command line?
3. Is it common to simply ask the user to add some text to their `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`?

### Desired result

Should be able to install cleanly with brew and then run `foo` as a command:

```
$ brew install script
$ foo
# => does the interesting thing
```

(Assume the brew formula is already installed locally. I'll worry about auditing and pushing the formula to homebrew later)

Comment: It is a common practice to save the current bash profile in a .bak file or something then modify it.

Comment: @VedaadShakib, I'm worried leaving behind those modifications when uninstalling with `brew uninstall foo`. I'm trying to find a more flexible approach that allows a clean installation. The .bak file approach runs into difficulty when many modifications have been made to `.bash_profile` AFTER the specific modification we wish to undo. It seems to me that finding the exact parts of the file that we wish to remove involves parsing the file, which I would like to avoid as it seems error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Refer https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/50232 and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/50231.

I have a script that safely‡ modifies ~/.bash_profile as part of a homebrew install process. https://github.com/paul-hammant/homebrew-tap/blob/master/switchjdk.rb

‡ allegedly

Answer (score 0):

Without using homebrew:

to put your bash scripts in some file such as `bashrc` or any other name works, then put the following line:

```
source "path/to/brew-script/script"
```

somewhere in your bash profile.

Then you just have to make sure you refresh or reload your bash profile by running `. ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bash_profile.`

How homebrew installs work:

When you installed homebrew it added a line to your bash_profile that modifies your $PATH variable to include the path to the homebrew install repo, so that whenever brew installs something it becomes findable through your PATH. 
If you use brew create you must have your script uploaded somewhere on the internet, because the argument brew install takes is a URL. I.e if I create my script at my_bash_function.tar.gz then I would do

```
brew create http://web.mit.edu/dianah13/www/my_bash_function.tar.gz
```

It also templates a pull request to include your package in homebrew's main repo.